# Getting Data from server using rest Api how to set the Data in a Text in react native

Tags: react-native

I am getting the data from server successfully i am not under standing how to set that data in a Text tag in React native here is my code please help.

```
 state = {
    data: []
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchFreelancerData();
  }
  fetchFreelancerData = async () => {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const response = await fetch(
      BaseUrl + "listing/get_freelancers?listing_type=single&profile_id=" + params.profile_id
    );
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json[0].name);
    this.setState({ fetchFreelancer: json });
  };
```

Here i am getting the response in json const successfully. i have also console the log as well and terminal is showing the name properly.But i am not understanding how to display the name in the Text tag.

this line  `console.log(json[0].name);` is getting the name properly.

```
<View style={styles.viewStyle}>
                        <Text style = {styles.nameStyle}>

                        </Text>
</View>
```

I have to set the name in the text as shown up here.

this is the response i am getting form server.

```
[
  Object {
    "_address": "",
    "_awards": Array [],
    "_educations": Array [],
    "_english_level": "",
    "_experience": Array [],
    "_featured_timestamp": "wt-featured",
    "_gender": "male",
    "_is_verified": "no",
    "_latitude": "",
    "_longitude": "",
    "_perhour_rate": "&#36;125.00",
    "_projects": Array [],
    "_tag_line": "The Future Of Memory",
    "badge": Object {
      "badget_color": "#e67e22",
      "badget_url": "https://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/featured.png",
    },
    "banner_img": "https://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/wp-content/themes/workreap/images/frbanner-350x172.jpg",
    "cancelled_jobs": 0,
    "completed_jobs": 1,
    "content": "",
    "favorit": "",
    "freelancer_link": "https://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/freelancer/wezalono-alone/",
    "location": Object {
      "_country": "Turkey",
      "flag": "https://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/img-01-4.png",
    },
    "member_since": "April 13, 2019",
    "name": "wezalono Alone",
    "ongoning_jobs": 0,
    "profile_id": 604,
    "profile_img": "https://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/29-1-100x100.jpg",
    "rating_filter": "5",
    "reviews": Array [
      Object {
        "_is_verified": "no",
        "employer_image": "https://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/img-01__2_-2.jpg",
        "employer_name": "pozev Jon",
        "level_sign": 1,
        "level_title": "Basic Level",
        "post_date": "April 13, 2019",
        "project_location": "australia",
        "project_rating": "5.00",
        "project_title": "Ecology Professor",
        "review_content": "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, saeunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim laborum. ",
      },
    ],
    "skills": Array [],
    "total_earnings": "&#36;0.00",
    "user_id": 63,
    "wt_average_rating": "5",
    "wt_total_percentage": "25",
    "wt_total_rating": "1",
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
{this.state.fetchFreelancer && 
<Text style = {styles.nameStyle}>{this.state.fetchFreelancer[0].name} . 
</Text>}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Text style = {styles.nameStyle}>{this.state.fetchFreelancer[0].name}</Text>
```

Comment: Showing this error ....
 TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.fetchFreelancer[0]')

Comment: did you console.log(this.state.fetchFreelancer)

Comment: i did not let me try

Comment: that means your state is not set properly: this one: this.setState({ fetchFreelancer: json });

Comment: Ok let me try this

Comment: I would suggest you to use componentDidMount instead of willMount as componentWillMount is depricated now

Comment: it is showing the same error...
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.fetchFreelancer[0]')

Comment: i am getting the complete array in ...
console.log(this.state.fetchFreelancer[0]);  };

Comment: if you get the complete array in this.state.fetchFreelancer[0], then you just need to check where your name is placed. can you show me the state you are getting in console.

Comment: fetchFreelancerData = async () => {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const response = await fetch(
      BaseUrl + "listing/get_freelancers?listing_type=single&profile_id=" + params.profile_id
    );
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ fetchFreelancer: json }); console.log(this.state.fetchFreelancer[0])   
  };

Comment: Please check my question i have added the complete responce which i am getting

Comment: replace data with your state fetchFreelancer. are you using data state anywhere?

Comment: No i am not using data state any where

Comment: you also need to define your state, I mean if you are not using your data state anywhere, just replace that state with fetchFreelacer like this: `fetchFreelancer: []`

Comment: Still getting the same Error